# Wowza Streaming Engine Manager could not connect to the Wowza Streaming Engine service(http://localhost:8087)

Tags: stream, localhost, wowza

i was installed Wowza streaming engine manager in my machine Ubuntu 18.04 ,
my IP Address is : `192.168.1.134`.
Then I wrote http://192.168.1.134:8088/enginemanager/ in my browser chrome it's give me this:
[web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3DQR.png) .
then i wrote the username and password : i found this  [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY1jA.png) .

```
 Wowza Streaming Engine Manager could not connect to the Wowza Streaming Engine service(http://localhost:8087). Verify that the Wowza Streaming Engine service has started and is running.
```

When I tried this command line : `sudo service WowzaStreamingEngine start` and `sudo service WowzaStreamingEngineManager start` , i found the same issue.

Please How can be resolve it .

NB: i tested Nginx server  to stream with Drone its work perfectly but with latency (<6s)  thats why i decide to   use WOWZA just for  streaming with drone in real time  , if you have other solution recommended it .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like your Wowza Streaming Engine is not running. Can you confirm by going to `http://[wowza-ip-address]:1935` or in your case `http://192.168.1.134:1935`? You should see your license and build details.

Comment: `Wowza Streaming Engine 4 TSRh Forum Edition (tonyweb @2015) 4.3.0 build16025`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you are running an unauthorized version of Wowza Streaming Engine. Please obtain an authorized license or trial license from Wowza.

I recommend uninstalling and deleting the unauthorized or "cracked" version you are currently running. It is likely causing the unexpected behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply : FYI i used this version cracked because i dont know how can be tested Wowza in my machine Ubuntu 18.04 with free trial : please how can be tested it without serial license . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure, I am the Developer Community Manager at Wowza. This is what we suggest you do when you get that error:

Verify that the Wowza Streaming Engine service has started and is running. Why? By default, Wowza Streaming Engine server software and Streaming Engine Manager install as system services and both should start automatically when you start your computer.

Troubleshooting:

1. Confirm that Wowza Streaming Engine is running:

Open a web browser and enter the URL:
http://[wowza-ip-address]:1935/ServerVersion
([wowza-ip-address] is the IP address or domain of the Wowza Streaming Engine server.)

If Wowza Streaming Engine installed correctly, the browser displays the Wowza Streaming Engine version number.
If not, make sure that the server is running and that TCP port 1935 is open on your router, firewall, and/or software firewall (iptables on Linux).

2. Make sure that you have the appropriate ports open to access the Wowza Streaming Engine and Wowza Streaming Engine Manager services, and that HTTP requests are being routed correctly through these ports. See our website ans search "Streaming Engine ports."
3. If the appropriate ports aren't open, check your server's firewall configuration to make sure it isn't blocking them.
4. After opening ports, you must stop and restart Wowza Streaming Engine and Wowza Streaming Engine Manager. Please review how to start and stop Engine instructions.

Hope this helps you and anyone else. This is a commonly asked question in Wowza Support.